# generate sql to run in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following tables

Table `A`:

```
ENTERPRISE_MAIN_CODE  ENTERPRISE_SUB_CODE  ENTERPRISE_DESCRIPTION
--------------------  -------------------  ----------------------
1                     0                    A
2                     0                    B
3                     0                    C
4                     0                    D
5                     0                    E
6                     0                    F
7                     0                    G
8                     0                    H
9                     0                    I
```

Table `B`:

```
ID_NO  ENTERPRISE_MAIN_CODE  ENTERPRISE_SUB_CODE
-----  --------------------  -------------------
1      1                     1
2      1                     2
3      7                     1
4      4                     1
5      4                     1    
6      6                     1
7      6                     5
```

Table `C`:

```
ID_NO  ENTERPRISE_ID_NO  ENTERPRISE_DATE  ENTERPRISE_AMT
-----  ----------------  ---------------  --------------
1      1                 20130109         1000
1      2                 20130315         2000
2      3                 20120120         3000
2      4                 20120305         4000
3      5                 20141111         5000
4      6                 20130115         6000
5      7                 20130320         7000
```

User inputs only month and year: for example 201303.

The date format is yyyymmdd

Output details: it has 4 parts which are explained below:

1. User should see the count and the amount of the selected year and month (201303 i.e 2013 march data)
2. The previous year of the selected year and month (count and the amount) (201203 i.e 2012 march data)
3. The first month of selected year till the selected year's selected month (count and the amount) (20130101 - 20130330)
4. The first month of previous year till the previous year's  month  (count and the amount) (i.e 20120101 - 20120330)

The expected output is as follows:

```
ENTERPRISE_DESCRIPTION  count  amt   count  amt   count  amt    count  amt
----------------------  -----  ----  -----  ----  -----  -----  -----  ----
A                       1      2000  1      4000  2      3000   2      7000
B                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
c                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
D                       1      7000  0      0     2      13000  0      0
E                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
F                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
G                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
H                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
I                       0      0     0      0     0      0      0      0
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) SO is not a magical code generator...

Comment: ... and if he has tried something, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this, which might handle several things you could face when doing this kind of report:

[Counting records by year and month including zero counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789777/counting-records-by-year-and-month-including-zero-counts/21792028#2179202)

I could be more specific if you'd given more specifics, like the OP did in the thread I cited.